# How can i get an index of an Array in an Array of a Json Doc

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have a Json Doc which i get from my back end which looks like the one below. It has an emails Array which the doc under it has and email array. I need to get the index the email array is part of which has a match for an email address so i can update the doc. i used lodash before to search for a key in a array of docs before with _.find and _.indexOf but not sure how this would work in an Array of Array case.

```
{
  "_type": "email_campaign",
  "status": "Active",
  "start_date": "04/17/2020",
  "template_id": "template::0a2decdd-3acd-4661-9721-1a9ec0d039e6",
  "summary": "Update",
  "metrics": {
    "first_email_sent": "",
    "last_email_send": "2020-04-17T22:11:52.317Z",
    "nbr_of_emails": 185,
    "nbr_of_bounces": 1,
 },
 "history": {
    "created_on": "04/17/2020 13:24:33",
  },
  "emails": [
    {
      "email": [
        "DCustomer@gmail.com"
      ],
      "track_request": "track_request::da07bd4b-b03e-4ecc-9d90-32e85cdb5b3a",
      "tracking_nbr": "MD1dpjR6d"
    },
    {
      "email": [
        "ACustomer@matcocomponents.com",
        "BCustomer@matcocomponents.com",

      ],
      "track_request": "track_request::6f64cee1-d38e-4d68-94a2-c3c7d1287984",
      "tracking_nbr": "YM1sMRX3nl"
    },
    {
      "email": [
        "ACustomer@gmail.com"
      ],
      "track_request": "track_request::92606d4f-f9e6-457f-9156-167eb068f05b",
      "tracking_nbr": "gj6dwIyHdE"
    },

  ],
  "_id": "3ed76589-4063-49f6-a21e-9ca16981d102"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **findIndex** and **includes**:

```
const index = docs.emails.findIndex(item => item.email.includes('ACustomer@matcocomponents.com'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
emailToFind="xxxxxxxxx"
var indexes=[]
var test= res.emails.map((el1,i1)=>{
  el.email.map((el2,i2)=>{
    if (el2===emailToFind){
      indexes.push(i1)
    }
  })
})
```